# Office365 custom page timeout

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, sharepoint, kendo-ui

I have a huge form that is supposed to be filled by user. As the form is quite long i have added auto save feature to the form but still the form has too much of write up to be done and so it takes almost 1.5 hours for users to fill the form.

So when user clicks on the submit button. He gets forbidden error. I have thought of splitting the form into pages, does any one has a better solution than this?

Comment: Please add more details to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create Wizard based form with sections in it and keep saving it to list on every screen save. this is the best solution i can think of.

additionally, load the page in designer view and check any other web part is not consuming the connection or creating error for you.

Comment: Thanks a lot vikash, I have already divided the form into sections with paging feature. That actually worked for me and also i have added a auto save feature at every 2 mins since the page is idle.